# Automate an sql script in power bi

Tags: sql, powerbi, scheduled-tasks, toad-data-point

I am using Toad for Oracle 14.2 database it
I have an sql script which checks duplicates and not nulls in various columns (and tables) and returns a count of rows if nulls or duplicates exist.
This data integrity test script is run every two weeks. The script is written in a way that the results of the query are spooled into a text file in a shared folder.

I wish to automate it and schedule its run every two weeks.
I know this can be done in a crontab using Linux.

But I would like to know how could it be achieved using POWER BI with a scheduled refresh

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is super-easy in Power BI, once you get the Oracle drivers installed on both your dev environment and on the On-Prem gateway you set up.

This would simply be an import mode Dataset with a custom SQL Statements and a scheduled refresh.

You may have to break the script up into multiple queries in Power Query.  If they all return the same columns you can merge them into a single table in the Power BI model.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, all sql tests in the main script return the same columns (description/title of the test, count) @david-browne-microsoft